# regex in sed not working as in PCRE

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have this source file.c:

```
#include <dir/header1>
#include <dir/header2>
#include <dir/header3>
...
```

I would like to match only those headers after dir, (e.g. `header1`). I do this:

```
$ sed -En 's/\/(.*)>/\1/p' file.c
```

but the will output:

`#include <dirheader1`, so it matched from the beginning of line, But I wanted to group from `/` character (therefor `s/\/...`). So I have tried:

```
$ sed -En 's/<.*\/(.*)>/\1/p' file.c
```

Neither that helped. So how to achieve that?

Comment: For clarity on what is expected, show us the output you are expecting from your sed command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract only the `headerx` bit of the three lines that you show with the `s///` command in `sed`, you will have to *remove* all bits of the line that you don't want.

The bits of the line that you don't want is the initial `#include <dir/` string at the start, and the final `>` string at the end.  This must all be matched by your regular expression.  Then also use a capture group for the bit in-between the initial and final strings to replace *the whole line* with the captured string:

```
sed -n 's,.*/\(.*\)>,\1,p' file.c
```

or, more explicitly,

```
sed -n 's,^#include <dir/\(.*\)>,\1,p' file.c
```

Comment: Why is need to match the whole line? for example, say if I have comments after `>`, then I would to what you said : `sed -n 's,.*/\(.*\)>.*,\1,p' file.c` , just added `.*`, after `>` so `sed` knows the line continue, but why is it needed? Perl does not need to slurp the whole line, it is sufficient for perl to just match, doesn't have to know look arounds. Why does `sed` needs to?

Comment: @autistic456 You are correct about having to add `.*` to match the _rest_ of the line in case there are comments, but there were none in your example. If you say `s/a\(.*\)c/A\1C/` and apply that to the string `abacus`, I would expect it to result in `AbaCus`, not in `AbaC`, that is, the substitute command only substitutes the bit of the input string that matches the expression. I believe this to be true in Perl as well.

Comment: Ok, get it know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not discarding the first part of the match so you could correct your code to do that.. as per @kusalananada

Alternatively a generic match using a negated pattern

```
sed -En "s|[^/]+/([^>]+)>|\1|p" file
```

For a specific match for `#include`

```
sed -En "s|^#include <dir/([^>]+)>|\1|p" file
```

Or with `grep` though you

```
grep -Po "(?<=#include <dir/)[^>]+" file
```

Or with `gawk`

```
awk -F"/|>" '$1~include{print $(NF-1)}' file
```